# Kernel crash with InputField[Dynamic]

Tags: dynamic

```
InputField[Dynamic[h, (h = #) &], FieldSize -> 20]

Dynamic[h]
```

When we enter `h=1.1+x`, the program exits. However, with `h=11/10 + x`, it is ok. I would like to know where I am going wrong, please. Thank you.

Comment: Does it happen after `ClearAll[x]`

Comment: This does not happen for me on version 12 on a fresh kernel. Can you elaborate? Did you try it with a fresh kernel? Do you have other definitions? What version of Mathematica are you using, and on what operating system? (And welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange!)

Comment: Also works fine for me on v.9.

Comment: The version we use is the  7.0 for student.